# How do I end standard input without a newline character?

Tags: command-line, input

I press Ctrl+D to end standard input, but it only works if I'm on a fresh line.  And that requires me to push Enter first, which puts an unwanted new line character in there.  Is there any way around that?

Comment: This is in bash? Running a script or a program (in C, C++)?

Comment: @Huckle: Any program that reads from standard input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ctrl-D` does not work only on a fresh line as you say. Take `rev` for example, which reverses each input line.

Normally, you press Enter after input, and it reverses that line:

```
$ rev
asdf
fdsa
```

If you do not want to append a newline to your input, just press `Ctrl-D` *twice* after you input `asdf`, it will be reversed in the same line:

```
$ rev
asdffdsa
```

Different programs handle this differently; for example `bc` does not behave like above.